# Active Admin Navigation Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

How do you add your own custom links dynamically to the ActiveAdmin global navigation header other than registering the pages/models? For example, if I want a link that can direct users to my home page for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like ActiveAdmin made it somewhat easier. I upgraded to version 0.6.2 and here is what you can do to add custom links anywhere in your navigation (the example below will add one custom menu item, and one custom dropdown):

In # config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu do |menu|
      menu.add :label => "My Custom Link", :url => "/", :priority => 0

      menu.add :label => "Pages" do |pages|
        pages.add :label => "Homepage", :url => "/admin/homepage"
        pages.add :label => "About Us", :url => "/admin/about-us"
        pages.add :label => "Facebook", :url => "http://www.facebook.com", :html_options => { :target => "_blank" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In case you already registered models with "Pages" as a parent menu (ie: in your app/admin/ folder, a model with `menu :priority => 2, parent: 'Pages'`) it will keep those as well automatically!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to to this by adding the ActiveAdmin::MenuItem to the current AdminAdmin controller. For example,

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :name_space => :example_namespace do
  controller do
    private
    def current_menu
      item = ActiveAdmin::MenuItem.new :label => "Link Name", :url => 'http://google.com'
      ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:example_namespace].menu.add(item)
      ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:example_namespace].menu
    end
  end
end
```

I basically created a new **ActiveAdmin::MenuItem** and add it to the current ActiveAdmin menu with the namespace **example_namespace** and return the menu in the end of the **current_menu** method. Note: **current_menu** is a method expected by **ActiveAdmin** so don't change the name of it. You can add as many items you like and each of these items will be converted to a link on your navigation header. Note this works for ActiveAdmin version > 0.4.3 so you might need to do your own digging if you want to do it for version <= 0.4.3.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminPage do
  menu :url => proc{ "#{AppConfig.url}/checkins/#{current_admin_user.try(:id)}" }
end
```

Here, you can use any of your db field values in the URL parameter to construct your own URL.

Comment: no need to do AppConfig with ````url: -> { "#{request.base_url}/"}````

Comment: Thanks Man :) @jakub

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the site title in your active admin initializer. For example:

```
    config.site_title_link = "/"
```

This will give you a link to your rootpage.